# Get content including tags of tag with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to get the content of a XML tag including other tags. For example I got this xml:

```
<aa>
  <bb>
    <cc>foo</cc>
  </bb>
</aa>
```

And I need to get:

```
<bb>
  <cc>foo</cc>
</bb>
```

I tried to do this with:

```
[...]
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
[...]
```

But I always get this result:

```
  foo
```

When I add some more nodes the output is always formatted as if the tags would still be there - but no matter what I try I don't get them in the output.

Comment: `[...]
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
[...]` is far too little information for us to have any idea how to fix your XSLT.

Comment: Try the     <xsl:template match="aa"><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>   </xsl:template>. It will remove the parent tag